# Understanding how DependencyProperty works and is implemented

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, silverlight-4.0

The Silverlight/WPF DependencyProperty enables data binding and indicates when the property has changed in value, without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. My question is on how does this work at the low level - how does DependencyProperty or [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) perform this change notification when neither DependencyObject, DependencyProperty, nor DispatcherObject define any events. Would this have something to do with the [DispatcherObject.Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property?

> Dependency properties, or the DependencyObject class, do not natively
>   support INotifyPropertyChanged for purposes of producing notifications
>   of changes in DependencyObject source property value for data binding
>   operations.

This excellent clarification was taken word-for-word from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Dependency properties are tightly integrated with the binding system internally. So instead of "notifying that the property changed", the code that sets the dependency property can call directly into the binding system and tell it to updated.

Similarly, things like inherited/attached properties can be updated on any descendant elements and/or the layout/measure/arrange can be updated. It can even tell any triggers (in Styles or ControlTemplates) to be reevaluated.

The Dispatcher isn't really related, but may be used during the process.

So in short, it's baked into WPF/Silverlight.

Comment: "Dependency properties can be used only by DependencyObject types" from the links ref above. DependencyObject derives from DispatcherObject.

Comment: @Webster - Yes, that's true. Did you have a question about that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you register a DependencyProperty you provide a callback to be called when the value changes.

[Here](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) you have more details. I don't think anything else is public about the internals of WPF. I might be wrong.